# can't do normal formating using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am a newbie in laravel and bootstrap. I spent already 2 hours trying to make normal formatting, but the result is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl0ER.png)

What i'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="{{action('OrderController@setDiscont')}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="input-group {{ $errors->has('discont') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <span class="col-md-7">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Скидка" name="discont" class="form-control" value="{{$discont or ""}}">
                                        </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn col-md-5">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Установить" class="btn-block btn btn-default" > 
                                        </span>
            <div class="help-block">
                @if ($errors->has('discont'))
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('discont') }}</strong> @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="{{action('OrderController@setClient')}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="input-group {{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <span class="col-md-7">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="телефон" id="phone"  name="phone" class="form-control" value="{{ old('phone') }}">
                                        </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn col-md-5">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Найти" class="btn btn-primary" > 
                                        </span>
            <div class="help-block">
                @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong> @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable example through jsfiddle for example.

Comment: You need to define 'normal' formatting

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for input groups. I'm assuming this is what you wanted from your css classes, but you can also check out the documentation for [inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) if that's what you wanted.

```
<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('discont') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Скидка" name="discont" class="form-control" value="{{$discont or ""}}">
                <div class="input-group-addon" style="padding:0;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Установить" class="btn-block btn btn-default" style="border: 0px;border-radius: 0px; background-color: #ddd;"> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="help-block">
             @if ($errors->has('discont'))
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('discont') }}</strong>
             @endif                  
            </div>
        </div>   
    </form>
</div>    

<div class="row">
    <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" placeholder="телефон" id="phone"  name="phone" class="form-control" value="{{ old('phone') }}">
                <div class="input-group-addon" style="padding:0;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Установить" class="btn-block btn btn-default" style="border: 0px;border-radius: 0px; background-color: #ddd;"> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="help-block">
             @if ($errors->has('phone'))
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
             @endif                  
            </div>
        </div>   
    </form>
</div>
```